# Pass a string as an id name into jQuery from an array javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a javascript that randomly takes a string from an array and uses it as a jQuery selector but I don't know how.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
    var array = ["img1", "img2", "img3", "img4", "img5", "img6", "img7", "img8", "img9", "img10", "img11"];
    $("id[name^=array[x]]").click(function() {
        var src1 = $("id[name^=array[x]]").attr("src");
        var src2 = $("#img").attr("src");
        if (src1 != src) {
            $("#img").attr("src", src1);
        }
    });
    $("id[name^=array[x]]").trigger("click");
})
```

It doesn't work if I write `"id[name^=array[x]]"`, it says:

```
"Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: id[name^=array[x]]"
```

Comment: `"id[name^=" + array[x] + "]"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
    var array = ["img1", "img2", "img3", "img4", "img5", "img6", "img7", "img8", "img9", "img10", "img11"];
    var $id = $("[name^=" + array[x] + "]");
    console.log($id);
    $id.click(function () {
        var src1 = $id.attr("src");
        var src2 = $("#img").attr("src");
        if (src1 != src) {
            $("#img").attr("src", src1);
        }
    });
    $id.trigger("click");
});
```

**EDIT:**

Your selector is wrong here. So, if you want to select elements w/ id like `img1`, `img2`, etc. you need to use:-

```
var $id = $("[id^=" + array[x] + "]");
```

In case you want to get elements with name like `img1`, `img2`, etc. you need to use:-

```
var $name = $("[name^=" + array[x] + "]");
```

Please modify the code based on your requirements.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Problem solved, I wrote like this: var src = $("#"+array[x]).

Comment: @BobernacAlexandru Cool. If the `img1` is just a id you can use it simply like that. Please do mark the [answer as accepted](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5235) to help other users too.